# O quanto o custo de acesso de um unodered_map pode atrapalhar na performance de um jogo?

Tags: c++, desempenho, hashmap, stl, c++17

O custo de acesso ao `unordered_map` pode ocasionar queda de FPS em um jogo se for acessado milhares de vezes por segundo?

```
class var
{
public:
    template < typename t = double > 
    static inline auto get( const std::string& var_name ) -> t& 
    { 
         return ( t& ) m_vars[ var_name ]; 
    }
private:
    static inline std::unordered_map< std::string, double > m_vars;
};

// Isso vai ficar rodando infinitamente em vários loops
// Não vai ser apenas uma vez que vou chamar o método get, vou chamar varias e varias vezes em vários loops diferente
// Acredito que o acesso ao map vai comprometer muito o desempenho do jogo ocasionando perda de fps
if ( var::get< bool >( "ativar_efeitos" ) )
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difícil responder sem um contexto, mas é altamente improvável que isso afete significativamente, pelo menos não por ele. Claro que a função que cálculo do código *hash* usada para mapear, a qualidade dela, as chaves que usar, e como é usado no geral poderia afetar alguma coisa, mas ainda assim, teria que ser tudo muito trágico para afetar um pouco. Esse rodando infinitamente já preocupa um pouco mais, não sei se deveria, mas o problema nada tem a ver com o mapa.

E se precisa de um mapa, não adianta mudar para outra coisa. Se pode usar outra coisa de boa e é algo melhor, então deveria usar.

Fico pensando também se essa é uma boa estratégia, ou se C++ é a linguagem adequada se está fazendo isso. Mas só um contexto muito detalhado para saber.

Não sei nem se esse código deveria ser escrito assim. Na forma postada não deveria.

Pra falar a verdade a pergunta é um pouco ingênua, o que provavelmente indica que fará vários outros erros muito mais graves que esse que afetarão bem mais, e nem perceberá.

Comment: Esse acesso vai ficar acontecer enquanto o jogo estiver rodando, toda a função que precisar usar uma variável eu usaria a função get em vez da variável porque ao meu ver fica bem mais organizado do que encher o projeto de variáveis globais ou colocar tudo dentro de uma namespace.

Sobre a função de hash estou usando uma biblioteca(cx_fnv1) para fazer o hash da string, nos meus testes ficou muito mais rápido.

E por que você acha que o código não deveria ser escrito assim? Estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Não use variáveis globais. Use variáveis em um escopo específico, mas use variáveis, não um mapa, eles não foram criados para isto. Não posso dar detalhes sem conhecer o todo, mas uma classe que só tem uma mapa vazio e um `get()` parece errado, o nome da classe parece errado, o generalização parece errada. Mas pelo que comentou agora, tudo parece errado.

Comment: A classe ainda não está completa ainda não terminei de escrever, ainda pretendo criar métodos para salvar/carregar a variável em um arquivo, por isso que eu acho que criar uma classe com um map seria o ideal pois eu poderia salvar/ler todos os valores de todas as variáveis com um simples for each.

Comment: ééé.... não....

Comment: Poderia indicar uma alternativa melhor? A unica coisa que eu consigo pensar e que atenda minhas necessidades no momento seria um map.

Comment: Faz uma classe estática e boa, não tem porque criar uma mapa. Ou então faz em Ruby, Lua, outra linguagem. Se vai fazer em C++ use os recursos de C++.